# AICC/HACP sample packages repository

Tags: scorm

I am searching for AICC/HACP sample packages on internet, but i didn't find any.

Can any one please provide sample packages repository for AICC/HACP.

Comment: AICC/HACP sample contents not available in online. If any one post here it will be helpful for every one, who is looking for this.

I don't think this question is eligible for negative vote.

Comment: I don't know about HACP but I know linkedin learning uses AICC and someone sent me one of those for AICC testing.

Comment: I gave you an upvote, its a valid question.

Comment: send me a direct message I have an AICC package I can share with you.